# Can we have a feature that can get source's meta info to know the layer id and layer type when add a unknown vector tile services?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Can we have a feature that can get source's meta info to list layers's id and layer's type when add a unknown vector tile service? I think these can help us to style vector service in right way,and can made a default style for different layers (point--circle,polygon--fill,line--line).

Answer (score 2):

You can call `map.getStyle().layers` to find the layers defined in the current style.

Here is how you can get the `id` and the `type` of each layer:

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
    zoom: 13,
    center: [-122.447303, 37.753574]
});

map.on('load', function () {    
    var layersMeta = map.getStyle().layers
        .map(function(layer) { 
            return [layer.id, layer.type];
        });
   console.log(layersMeta);   
});
```

And here's [the corresponding jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmandov/k7sakkhu/). Have a look at the console.

Comment: I mean that if i don't know the source's layers.For example:`map.addSource()`to add a custom vector layer service,so maybe sometimes we don't know the source's layer id and layer name,so if there is a function to get the source's meta info may very useful,so we can add the source with a default style.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no standard way to list all the layers in a vector tile source. Mapbox sources provide a `vector_layers` object in their TileJSON but because this feature is not standard, it is not available within the GL JS API.